# join in laravel using "with" & set where statement in joined table

Tags: laravel, join, orm, eloquent

i write my code like this :

```
    $teams = TeamTeam::query()
        ->selectRaw('team_teams.title, team_teams.team_structure_id, team_teams.id,
         team_teams.description')
        ->join('team_structures','team_teams.team_structure_id',"=",'team_structures.id')
        ->where('team_structures.organization_id',session()->get('organization_id'))
        ->orderBy('team_structures.created_at','desc');
    $teams = $teams->get();
```

i want to use from with instead of join like :

TeamTeam::with('TeamStructure')... and set where statement in team_structures table. how can i use that??!!

thanks.

Comment: I think we need a little bit more information than that. Maybe your current result and expected result.

Comment: i want join using "with" like with('TeamStructure') and set where statement on that ; my current result is correct. i want to know how can i write code with that statement!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$teams = TeamTeam::with(['TeamStructure' => function ($q1){
            $q1->where('organization_id', session()->get('organization_id'))->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
        }])
        ->whereHas('TeamStructure', function ($q2){
            $q2->where('organization_id', session()->get('organization_id'))->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
        })
        ->select('title', 'team_structure_id', 'id', 'description')
        ->get();
```